# Database management tool that support Database server address in IPv6 format

Tags: jdbc, ipv6, sap-ase, database-management, dbvisualizer

I use Sybase ASE 15.5 on Windows server 2008 and use Sybase central (JDBC driver) for management. After configured my machine to IPv6 only mode ( pure IPv6) and correct the DSEDIT connection properties, I can ping Datase server and access Database by the ISQL utility (Open client program in C++).

However, the Sybase central does not allow IPv6 address in the Host name field

i.e:

IPv4:

```
[Server1]
master=TCP,192.168.1.1,5000
query=TCP,192.168.1.1,5000
```

IPv6:

```
[Server1]
master=TCP,2001:ab1::12:1,5000
query=TCP,2001:ab1::12:1,5000
```

I tried some other JDBC tool like DbVisualizer but it only allow IPv4, not IPv6

i.e:

```
jdbc:jtds:sybase://192.168.1.1:5000;DatabaseName=MyDB

jdbc:jtds:sybase://2001:ab1::12:1:5000;DatabaseName=MyDB
```

Is there any Database management tool (JDBC driver) that support the Database server address in IPv6 format?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put brackets [ ] around the IPv6 address. It is mandatory in URLs and might work here as well.

Another way might be to connect using a hostname that resolves to an IPv6 address. Either by using DNS or your local hosts file.

Comment: I tried it, however it does not work. The problem is the Sybase central's (or DbVisualizer's) IP validation. They only allow IPv4 format input. Additon, the [IPv6] is used in web browser.